# How to notify when thirdparty application gets called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

When third party apps in mobiles gets called i would like to notify user in a text message ..I am creating an app that will notify the user when i tries to open an application .
Help me to receive intent when ever app is tries to open..else sugges me some steps to find when the app icon is being clicked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start a service, and execute every single minutes. Use `ActivityManager` to get the top activity in current running task. Something like this:

`ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService("activity");

    ComponentName topActivity = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;`

And then, you can do anything you want. Hope useful to u.
Don't forget the permission:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>`

Comment: Do we need to give any permission for this..?

Comment: @GaneshKumar  add this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>  `